# CouchDb (Cloudant) mapreduce: what's the maximum number of emits per document?

Tags: mapreduce, couchdb, cloudant

I have a Cloudant db with 5 different document types.
As I have full control of the updates to one document type I plan to use one document with an array with 60k values instead of creating 60k documents because it will make my update process easier.

It appears that during the map phase where I create one entry for each of the 60k values in the document the update process is timing out.

Is this to be expected? Will my performance be much better if I actually create 60k documents?
The db will have about 500k documents to start with and my mapreduce will find the related documents (can be several hundred) and combine the data to one return object.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the limit is on the number of emits per map function, but 60K seems like quite a bit. I think if you have that many emits per map function, then your documents are too big. I would recommend breaking this into separate documents.

Answer (score 0):

CouchDB index is same B+Tree as CouchDB data file. That means there is no limit for number of emits.

Comment: I agree, Antonio. From the BTree perspective there should not be an issue. What I found during tests is that the map phase is timing out sometimes when trying to perform 30k+ emits. Maybe there are some settings on the server side. otherwise I will have to reduce the emits

Comment: When you try to pass 30k emits over the view server, you should remember that server is given 10 seconds to process a request. See http://docs.couchdb.org/en/1.6.1/config/query-servers.html#query_server_config/os_process_limit for details